# Convert rows to column with possible combinations

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I need to convert one query result to table with possible combinations. please see details as below:

This is my original result which is returned by select query (Field can be upto n numbers).
[image]

I want output like this:

[image: I want output like this:]

I have tried Pivot but seems not works to me, i have applied logic on C# code which generates same result but its taking time to generate result. Anyone have idea how can i do it on SQL Server?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your output doesn't make much sense to me. You turned 5 rows into 4 and the columns are just random. Can you explain the logic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work for your example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T.ID
    , FIELD_1356.FIELD_1356
    , FIELD_1359.FIELD_1359
    , FIELD_1362.FIELD_1362
FROM
    YourTable T
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT FieldValue FIELD_1356 FROM YourTable WHERE ID = T.ID AND FieldName = 'FIELD_1356') FIELD_1356
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT FieldValue FIELD_1359 FROM YourTable WHERE ID = T.ID AND FieldName = 'FIELD_1359') FIELD_1359
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT FieldValue FIELD_1362 FROM YourTable WHERE ID = T.ID AND FieldName = 'FIELD_1362') FIELD_1362
```

And for a dynamic SQL solution for an unknown quantity of IDs and fields you could use:

```
DECLARE @Fields table (FieldName varchar(255))

INSERT INTO @Fields
SELECT DISTINCT FieldName FROM YourTable

DECLARE
    @SelectSection varchar(max) = ''
    , @ApplySection varchar(max) = ''

SELECT @SelectSection = @SelectSection + ', ' + FieldName + '.' + FieldName
FROM @Fields
ORDER BY FieldName

SELECT @ApplySection = @ApplySection + ' ' + 'OUTER APPLY (SELECT FieldValue ' + FieldName + ' FROM YourTable WHERE ID = T.ID AND FieldName = ''' + FieldName + ''') ' + FieldName
FROM @Fields
ORDER BY FieldName

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) = 'SELECT DISTINCT T.ID' + @SelectSection + ' FROM YourTable T' + @ApplySection

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. your solution for dynamic SQL is working perfectly to me....:)

Answer (score 1):

```
with #all as 
  (select * from YourTable)
   select * from (select ID,
    ,case when FieldName  ='FIELD_1356 ' then 'FIELD_1356'
        when FieldName  ='FIELD_1359' then 'FIELD_1359'
        when FieldName  ='FIELD_1362' then 'FIELD_1362'
        end as seqno
    from #all
    ) as datatable
    pivot(
   Max([FIELDVALUE]) 
  for [seqno] in ([FIELD_1356],[FIELD_1359],[FIELD_1362])
  )as piv
```

Try this for the Pivot. It might give you what you are looking for.